Apex 23.2: Including a Badge Column in Excel Download
I have an interactive report where one of the columns is of type 'Badge'. The column displays as expected in the Interactive Report, but when the user downloads the report to Excel the badge column is omitted.
Is this a limitation of the Badge column type, or am I missing a setting? I looked for the 'Include When Printing' attribute that I have seen on other columns and it is nowhere to be found. Anyway around this?


